# jsoup parsing google.com search returns different results on win / linux

Tags: java, css, linux, windows, jsoup

I have the following code, running on my local Win 10 machine within Eclipse (java 7) and then deployed to a Red Hat server as a servlet running on Tomcat 7:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com/search?q=best+hotel+chicago&start=1" + i).ignoreHttpErrors(true).referrer("https://www.google.com").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36").followRedirects(true).timeout(15000).get();
Elements eSet = doc.select(".ads-ad a:not([style*=\"display:none\"])");
```

Running this on my local Win 10 machine I get a result set of paid Google advertisments on the page, but when I deploy this exact same code in the servlet and run it on the Red Hat machine, I get NO results using the same input page. I realize that Google is dynamically generating this page using jscript, but that does not explain the difference because it does work on my Windows machine.

Why is this happening? What context would explain these different results?

Here's the results on Win 10:

```
<a class="_Jwu r-ixVPx5JNUXrk" href="http://www.marriott.com/default.mi" id="vn1s0p1c0" onmousedown="return google.arwt(this)" ontouchstart="return google.arwt(this)" data-preconnect-urls="https://www.marriott.com/,http://clickserve.dartsearch.net/" jsl="$t t-zxXzjt1d4B0;$x 0;">Hotels In Chicago - Marriott's Best Rate Guarantee - marriott.com‎</a>
<a class="_Jwu r-iRYug3IuGb_A" href="https://www.hotels.com/de1497539-qu4/luxury-hotels-chicago-illinois/" id="vn1s0p2c0" onmousedown="return google.arwt(this)" ontouchstart="return google.arwt(this)" data-preconnect-urls="http://clickserve.dartsearch.net/" jsl="$t t-zxXzjt1d4B0;$x 0;">Top 10 Luxury Hotels in Chicago, Illinois - Hotels.com‎</a>
<a class="_Qwu" href="/shopping/seller?q=hotels.com&amp;hl=en&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwjtwO6RlMHYAhXF6yYKHShDBqAQwQYILA">Calificación</a>
<a class="_Bu" href="http://www.harrisinteractive.com/Insights/EquiTrendRankings/2015EquiTrendRankings.aspx?col104=open#CollapsiblePanel104" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','','AOvVaw1aVhv8iFKaZBaie0U2sGTC','','0ahUKEwjtwO6RlMHYAhXF6yYKHShDBqAQ9xsILg','','',event)">2015 Harris Poll EquiTrend</a>
<a class="_Jwu" href="http://www.hotels.com/?pos=HCOM_LATAM&amp;locale=en_MX" id="vads-0-0-2-1-0" onmousedown="return google.arwt(this)">Hotels.com Rewards</a>
<a class="_Jwu" href="http://www.hotels.com/deals/?pos=HCOM_LATAM&amp;locale=en_MX&amp;PSRC=AFF05" id="vads-0-0-2-1-1" onmousedown="return google.arwt(this)">Deal Finder</a>
<a class="_Jwu r-iZU8HqezARjc" href="https://www.jdvhotels.com/hotels/illinois/chicago/talbott-hotel" id="vn1s0p3c0" onmousedown="return google.arwt(this)" ontouchstart="return google.arwt(this)" data-preconnect-urls="http://www.jdvhotels.com/" jsl="$t t-zxXzjt1d4B0;$x 0;">Best Hotel In Downtown Chicago - Stay At The Luxurius Talbott‎</a>
<a class="_Bu" href="https://travel.usnews.com/Hotels/review-The_Talbott_Hotel-Chicago-Illinois-10014/" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','','AOvVaw3FnKilLnLJYICVDTz1jgVz','','0ahUKEwjtwO6RlMHYAhXF6yYKHShDBqAQ9xsINQ','','',event)">US News</a>
<a class="_Jwu" href="https://www.jdvhotels.com/hotels/illinois/chicago/talbott-hotel/20-east" id="vads-0-0-3-3-0" onmousedown="return google.arwt(this)">Dining Options</a>
<a class="_Jwu" href="https://www.jdvhotels.com/hotels/illinois/chicago/talbott-hotel/meetings" id="vads-0-0-3-3-1" onmousedown="return google.arwt(this)">Meetings And Events</a>
<a class="_Jwu" href="https://www.jdvhotels.com/hotels/illinois/chicago/talbott-hotel/rooms" id="vads-0-0-3-3-2" onmousedown="return google.arwt(this)">Book A Room</a>
<a class="_Jwu" href="https://www.jdvhotels.com/about/careers" id="vads-0-0-3-3-3" onmousedown="return google.arwt(this)">Career Opportunities</a>
<a class="_Jwu" href="https://www.jdvhotels.com/hotels/illinois/chicago/talbott-hotel/amenities" id="vads-0-0-3-3-4" onmousedown="return google.arwt(this)">Amenities Offered</a>
<a href="/aclk?sa=l&amp;ai=DChcSEwjw2PaRlMHYAhUeucAKHaz8ChEYABAGGgJpbQ&amp;sig=AOD64_3mOywZoffWgbDbEUhIf8i_92e1tw&amp;q=&amp;ctype=107&amp;ved=0ahUKEwjtwO6RlMHYAhXF6yYKHShDBqAQmxAIPQ&amp;adurl=" aria-hidden="true"><span class="_J2b"></span><span class="_vnd">20 E Delaware Pl, Chicago, IL</span></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-theme="0" data-width="-2" class="g-bbll ioz7YayzbDxY--XRAQhnJXLU" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" jsaction="r.saTe4DDW138" data-rtid="ioz7YayzbDxY" jsl="$x 1;" data-ved="0ahUKEwjtwO6RlMHYAhXF6yYKHShDBqAQ_kAIPg"><span class="_G2b"><span>Hoy abierto · Abierto las 24 horas</span><span class="mn-dwn-arw"></span></span></a>
<a class="_Jwu r-iocqcJJM2qAc" href="https://www.booking.com/city/us/chicago.html" id="vn1s0p4c0" onmousedown="return google.arwt(this)" ontouchstart="return google.arwt(this)" data-preconnect-urls="http://www.booking.com/" jsl="$t t-zxXzjt1d4B0;$x 0;">Best Hotels in Chicago, IL - Lowest price guarantee - booking.com‎</a>
<a class="_Jwu r-iRsLwQlU8vHQ" href="http://www.luxuryhotelsguides.com/?ufi=20033173" id="vn1s3p1c0" onmousedown="return google.arwt(this)" ontouchstart="return google.arwt(this)" data-preconnect-urls="http://www.luxuryhotelsguides.com/" jsl="$t t-zxXzjt1d4B0;$x 0;">Top 10 Luxurious Hotels Chicago - Best 5 Star Luxurious Hotels Chicago‎</a>
<a class="_Jwu" href="http://luxuryhotelsguides.com/?id=top10best" id="vads-3-0-1-1-0" onmousedown="return google.arwt(this)">Top 10 Best Luxury Hotels</a>
<a class="_Jwu" href="http://luxuryhotelsguides.com/?id=coolhotels" id="vads-3-0-1-1-1" onmousedown="return google.arwt(this)">Cool Luxury Hotels</a>
<a class="_Jwu" href="http://luxuryhotelsguides.com?id=luxurysl" id="vads-3-0-1-1-2" onmousedown="return google.arwt(this)">5 Star Luxury Hotels</a>
<a class="_Jwu" href="http://luxuryhotelsguides.com/?id=fast" id="vads-3-0-1-1-3" onmousedown="return google.arwt(this)">Fast &amp; Easy Hotel Booking</a>
```

On Red Hat this list is empty - no errors are produced. I do understand that this is against Google terms of service, but that is not the issue here.

Comment: It's not related to the OS. I installed Tomcat 8 on a Windows machine and it also produces no results. The same exact code running in Eclipse with Tomcat 8 (on a different machine) provides results. I also changed to a headless browser (htmlUnit) and am getting identical results as jSoup.